# jquery form validation multiple messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have sample form.

```
<form id="test_frm" name="test_frm" class="form" method="post">
        <fieldset data-pattern="stripes">
            <div>
                <label class="req"><i>*</i> Location</label>
                <div class='form-search-dropdown'>
                    <input type='text' class='form-search-field' name='' value=''><i class='form-icon dropdown'></i>
                    <ul id="sub_maintenance_locations">
                        {foreach from=$locations item="location"}
                            <li val="{$location->getId()}">{$location->getName()}</li>
                        {/foreach}
                    </ul>
                    <input type='hidden' class='dropdown-val' id="location_id" name='sub_maintenance_template[{$sub_maintenance_template_count}][location_id]' value=''>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div>
                <label class="req"><i>*</i> Problem</label>
                <div class='form-search-dropdown'>
                    <input type='text' class='form-search-field' name='' value=''><i class='form-icon dropdown'></i>
                    <ul id="problems">
                        {foreach from=$problems item="problem"}
                            <li val="{$problem->getId()}">{$problem->getName()}</li>
                        {/foreach}
                    </ul>
                    <input type='hidden' class='dropdown-val' id="problem_id" name='sub_maintenance_template[{$sub_maintenance_template_count}][problem_id]' value=''>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div>
                <label class="req"><i>*</i> Description</label>
                <textarea class="form-textarea" id="sub_task_description" name="sub_maintenance_template[{$sub_maintenance_template_count}][description]" style="height:120px;"></textarea>
                <i class="help"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="form-submit-container">
                <div class="pad">
                    <input type="button" class="form-submit js-create-subtask" value="Create Sub-task">
                    <span>or <a>Cancel</a></span>
                </div>
            </div>

        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

I am trying to vallllidate the form without making server call.

Validation code will be llike this -

```
$(document).off( 'click', '.js-create-subtask' ).on('click', '.js-create-subtask', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        boolIsValid = true;

        $('.js-no-subtasks').hide();
        $('#error_div .error').text('');

        if( '' == $('#maintenance_location_id').val() || '' == $('#maintenance_problem_id').val() || '' == $('#days_to_complete').val() ){
            $('#error_div .error').append('<i></i> Location is required. Problem is required. Days to complete is required.');
            $('#error_div .error').show();
            boolIsValid = false;
        } else if ( '' == $('#maintenance_problem_id').val() ){
            $('#error_div .error').append('<i></i> Problem is required.');
            $('#error_div .error').show();
            boolIsValid = false;
        } else if( '' == $('#days_to_complete').val() ){
            $('#error_div .error').append(' <i></i> Days to complete is required.');
            $('#error_div .error').show();
            boolIsValid = false;
        } else if( '' == $('#sub_task_description').val() ){
            $('#error_div .error').append(' <i></i> Description is required.');
            $('#error_div .error').show();
            boolIsValid = false;
        }

        if( true == boolIsValid ) {
            // if everything is fine.
        }
    });
```

First time whenever I tried for blank values it shows me right validation. But after selecting location from the drop down still it gives me validation location is required.(1st if case because problem & number of days not entered.) Is there any way that I get validation message without nested if cases?

Expected result :

- If user did not entered location,problem,no.of days complete &
  description it should execute first if case.
- If user selected
  location only it should show remaining error messages & vice versa.

Comment: please create a js fiddle or any other form where the issue can be replicable

Answer (score 0):

Your first if statement should use `&&` instead of `||`, otherwise it will always display the first message as long as you have one field missing.

```
if( '' == $('#maintenance_location_id').val() && '' == $('#maintenance_problem_id').val() && '' == $('#days_to_complete').val() ){}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if( '' == $('#maintenance_location_id').val() || '' == $('#maintenance_problem_id').val() || '' == $('#days_to_complete').val() )` will be true when **AT LEAST ONE OF THE CONDITIONS IS MET**, hence it does not matter you already selected a maintenance location, as long as the other two selects have not been picked, that `if` will be `true` and **WILL NOT** run the other conditions since they are in the form of `else if`.

This is why: *But after selecting location from the drop down still it gives me validation location is required*.

Regarding your expected results, you will need an `if-else` structure for 2^3=8 situations, and show a message for each.

This is only considering `#maintenance_location_id`, `#maintenance_problem_id` and `#days_to_complete`, not `#sub_task_description` which you do not include in your first `if`.

```
false false false  
false false true  
false true false  
true false false  
false true true 
true false true 
true true false  
true true true
```

I will leave that bit to you :). hope it helps